# How to remove separator lines on top and bottom of a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

My question is something similar to this. But the solutions out there dint work. [How to remove first cell top separator and last cell bottom separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668797/how-to-remove-first-cell-top-separator-and-last-cell-bottom-separator)
I have a tableview with 3 sections(which are dynamic). I am having a cell separator for each section.

```
   tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

That is how I have created it.
But, the separator is getting added on both top and bottom of each section along with the rows.
How can I delete the top and bottom lines for each section?

```
    tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 42
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

I am creating the tableView programmatically. So, I wouldn't be able to set the separator

[image]

Style to none and I need the separators for the remaining cells in the table.

Comment: IS that image is how you want the *bottom* of the last row in the section to look? and, I'm guessing, an upside-down version of that for the *top* of the first row?

Comment: You need remove separators only on top and bottom? is this what you need?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes. i need to remove them only on top and bottom

Comment: @DonMag No. That is how it is appearing on the bottom and top aswell. I want to remove them

Comment: @krishna - show an image of how you want your table to look.

Comment: tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear.    I have removed the separator and have created a label and added it as a separator. I am able to clear the separator line on the above of the table view . But how to hide the label on the last row for each section of the table view?@DonMag